# SPFx solution is giving error while cleaning the solution

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-code, spfx

I have created a SharePoint extension with SPFx framework. initially I ran the solution and it is working fine. But in second run I want to clean the solution. So I executed `gulp clean` command, but it is failing and producing different kind of errors seems each time. Sometimes error is coming on `gulp package-solution`, sometimes with `gulp build` command. 
Below is sample error:

```
Error - Unknown
 EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'E:\Practice\SharePoint\SPFx\Extensions2\HeaderFooter\temp\deploy\sp-fx-header-footer-application-customizer_4851d776c4c9f9fd9ef72c1f266114dc.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

remove temp folder and try gulp build again.
temp folder is created whenever we use gulp bundle or gulp package-solution to bundle js file. it also create a deploy folder. Js files in that folder will be paste to cdn folder on deployment time.

Comment: I have tried that already. But it is allowing me to delete the deploy folder